# How to avoid summarized items in pivot table

Tags: excel

I have a litttle bit of a problem, I have a list full of semi-raw data, from which I am building a pivot table. However, the problem is that I have a lot of double counting now.

Raw data looks like this

```
1
2
(1+2)=3
```

and so on; So, some values in the data are already summarized. Is there any way to tell excel that `3 = 1 + 2` in pivot table? Because now I am getting `1 + 2 + 3 = 6`, not something line `3 = 1 + 2`.

Hope it's clear what I am trying to solve now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a secondary field that with an IF checks if that row must be in your Pivot Table or not, and then later on, use that field in your Pivot Table as a Filter.

Comment: Does your raw data include literally "(1+2)=3" or does it just display "3" as the subtotal? From your example, I'm deducing it's actually just "3". So how do you know which lines are subtotals and not just separate values? You must have some formatting or values in another column that identify the subtotals. We need to know what that is to be able to help you exclude the subtotals.

Comment: I know which one is which because i have name for each of these values, so I can figure out which one is which. Thank you Foxfire and Burns